# NoMethodError: undefined method `get' for main:Object when I try to install webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack

I created a new rails application and when I try to launch the application, I got the error:

> "Webpacker configuration file not found".

So I tried to install webpacker with this command `"rails webpacker:install"` and I got this error:

```
rails aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `get' for main:Object
Did you mean?  gets
               gem
```

followed by a stack trace.

- My yarn version: 1.22.4
- My ruby version: ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux]
- My rails version: Rails 6.0.3.2

Comment: It may happens when node or yarn are not install properly. Run 'rails --task' to see a command to check the yarn and node installation.

Comment: Alternatively you may install ruby 2.6.6 or 2.5.6, which is stable with rails 6.x.x.

Comment: Webpacker is by default installed on rails 6. If you check the logs generated by rails new you may see it saying: 'installing webpacker'.

Comment: It had happens to me before, I have one gour avaliable to solve it with you. You can edit to include more logs, it would be nice if you show the log generated from 'rails new' command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the ruby version to the 2.5.6 through rvm and it works.

Thanks to @paulo-felipe-souza!